# ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible... selenium (python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting those annoying element is not visible exception using python's selenium, while the element is active, selected, and flashing.

The issue is on the page to make a jfiddle, so instead of making a fiddle of the fiddle itself here is a cut and paste way to log in and have a webdriver (named 'driver') in your ipython terminal (enter username and password into ipython, not the page):

https://gist.github.com/codyc4321/787dd6f62e71cc71ae83

Now there is a driver up and you're logged into jsfiddle, everything I do here fails except picking the box the first time (let's say I wanna drop CSS in the CSS box):

https://gist.github.com/codyc4321/f4c03c0606c2e3e4ff5b

Paste `activate_hidden_element` and the first codeline in and see the CSS panel light up. For some reason, this highlighted panel is 'not visible', and you can't paste and code in it. The item is

```
  <div class="window top" id="panel_css" data-panel_type="css">
    <textarea id="id_code_css" rows="10" cols="40" name="code_css"></textarea>
    <a href="#" class="windowLabel" data-panel="css">
      <span class="label">CSS</span><i class="bts bt-gear"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

All the other items (HTML, JS) are essentially the same. Why won't this active box allow text to paste in? Thank you

SOLUTION:

the ugly way I made this service work was to manually fake a cut and paste:

```
css_content = get_inline_content_and_remove_tags(webpage_content, 'style')

js_content = get_inline_content_and_remove_tags(webpage_content, 'script')

webpage_content = # ...clean cruft...

def copy_paste_to_hidden_element(content=None, html_id=None):
    pyperclip.copy(content)
    activate_hidden_element(html_id=html_id, driver=driver)
    call_sp('xdotool key from+ctrl+v')
    time.sleep(1)

copy_paste_to_hidden_element(content=webpage_content, html_id="panel_html")
copy_paste_to_hidden_element(content=js_content, html_id="panel_js")
copy_paste_to_hidden_element(content=css_content, html_id="panel_css")
```

It does work, the only minor issue is it can't run in the background, I need to leave the screen alone for about 30 seconds

Comment: the final goal is to fill the textarea, that's right?

Comment: yessir, be able to fill all those text areas html, css, and javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSFiddle editors are powered by [`CodeMirror`](https://codemirror.net/index.html) which has a *programmatic way to set editor values.*

For every JSFiddle editor you need to put values into, locate the element with a `CodeMirror` class, get the `CodeMirror` object and call [`setValue()`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api):

```
css_panel = driver.find_element_by_id("panel_css")

code_mirror_element = css_panel.find_element_by_css_selector(".CodeMirror")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(arguments[1]);",
                      code_mirror_element, 
                      "test")
```

---

Demo, using JS panel executing the `alert("Test");` Javascript code:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/")
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("user")
>>> driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value = 'Log in']").click()
>>> 
>>> driver.get("https://jsfiddle.net/")
>>> 
>>> js_panel = driver.find_element_by_id("panel_js")
>>> 
>>> code_mirror_element = js_panel.find_element_by_css_selector(".CodeMirror")
>>> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(arguments[1]);", code_mirror_element, "alert('test');")
>>> 
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("run").click()
>>>
```

It produces:

[image]

Comment: I need something like this for my own project, seems it's open source. appreciate it alex