# How to programmatically change the editors value in CodeMirror 6?

Tags: text, editor, codemirror

Calling `console.log(editor.state.doc)` reveals:

```
TextLeaf {
    text: ["Test Text"],
    length: 9,
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function
}
```

So the text or editors value is there, however if I call `editor.state.doc.text = ["New Test Text"]` I get missing text, so it doesn't seem to be the intended way to change it.

How do I actually do it?

### Pseudo Code

`editor.getDoc().setValue('New Test Text');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The necessary information can be found here: https://codemirror.net/examples/change/

Example:

```
editor.dispatch({
  changes: {from: 0, to: editor.state.doc.length, insert: 'New Test Text'}
});
```

`editor` being a `EditorView` instance.