Unable to insert text using Selenium
I am trying to automate a process using Selenium. I want to run a query in StackExchange Data Explorer. I am using selenium for automation. I am unable to input the query into the textarea using send_keys()

If you can see the image above, on the right side, we can see textarea tag. I am almost certain that this is where the query needs to go. But when I click on the textarea tag, it highlights nothing on the webpage. As I tried to run the code, I could not send_keys to the tag.
At first I thought maybe I was looking at the wrong tag, but if I go inside <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default"> below textarea tag, there is no other input or textarea tags. There are some span or pre tags but cannot send_keys to them either( which I thought so )? Why is it so?
Is there a get around for this ?

Please provide your current solution as a starting point.

probably useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844574/programmatically-edit-codemirror-contents-without-access-to-object
